# Need to remove SOAP Action from Savon generated request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, soap, wsdl, savon

I need to remove the SOAPAction from my request using Savon 2.

This is how I build the client:

```
client = Savon.client do
wsdl "http://servername:port/PingService?wsdl"
convert_request_keys_to :none
env_namespace :soapenv
namespaces({
 'xmlns:pin' => 'http://servername:port/pingService_v1'
 })
 end
```

I use the following call to make the request:

```
client.call(:invoke,  message:  { "pin:PingReq" => { "pin:PingDB" => "true", "pin:PingG" => "true" }})
```

This is the request that is sent:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://support.cxf.transport.mule.org/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pin="http://servername/pingService_v1">
<soapenv:Body>
<tns:invoke>
<pin:PingReq>
<pin:PingDB>true</pin:PingDB>
<pin:PingG>true</pin:PingG>
</pin:PingReq>
</tns:invoke>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

A valid request would have everything except for the tns:invoke tags.

Comment: Strange, but you can always build your body manually.

Comment: How would I build the body manually? Would I still use Savon? I am using Savon 2 if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Savon 2.x you can roll your own body by doing this:

```
client.call(:method, xml: "<tns:invoke><pin:PingReq> ...")
```

Comment: Thank you Steffan! I was able to get it working using

     client.call(:invoke, xml: "<soapenv:Envelope  xmlns="xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" ... ><soapenv:Body><pin:PingReq><pin:PingDB>...<soapenv:Envelope>"
`

Comment: kind of ugly but it will work for the app I am creating for the time being.

Comment: Yeah, it's the last thing you do when nothing else works. Keeps you employed ;-)